# Call another ajax inside ajax till first will complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax for performing some operation in my web. I want to call another ajax in every seconds until the first ajax response come. My ajax code is :-

```
$.ajax({
                    url  : $(this).attr('action'),
                    type    : $(this).attr('method'),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data    : $(this).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() {
                            var row = '<tr id="row_'+i+'">';
                            row += '<td>'+$('#fileid').val()+'</td>';       
                            row += '<td>'+$('#resolution').val()+'</td>';       
                            row += '<td>'+$('#bitrate').val()+'</td>';      
                            row += '<td>'+$('#ndrive').val()+'</td>';       
                            row += '<td>'+$('.type').val()+'</td>';     
                            row += '<td>'+curr_date+'-'+curr_month+'-'+curr_year+'</td>';
                            row += '<td>'+hours+':'+minute+':'+second+'</td>';
                            row += '<td><div id="process-bar" class="process-bar" style="height: 18px;"> </div></td>';
                            row += '</tr>';     
                            $('#stastistics tbody').prepend(row);       
                            $('#fileid').val('');
                            $('#ndrive').val('');
                            $('.type').val('');
                            $('#resolution').val('');
                            $('#bitrate').val('');
                    },
                    success : function(data) 
                    {
                        if(data.status == 'error')
                        {
                            var html = '<span class="label label-danger">Error</span>';
                            $("tr#row_"+i+" td:nth-child(8)").find('#process-bar').remove();
                            $("tr#row_"+i+" td:nth-child(8)").html(html);
                        }
                        else if(data.status == 'success')
                        {
                            var html = '<span class="label label-success">Success</span>';
                            $("tr#row_"+i+" td:nth-child(8)").find('#process-bar').remove();
                            $("tr#row_"+i+" td:nth-child(8)").html(html);
                        }
                    },
                    error   : function( xhr, err ) 
                    {

                    },
                });
```

This is ajax take a long time to complete so i want to show a progress for this process. so i want to call a another ajax in every second so it update the progress data in every second. How can i call another ajax inside this ajax till response of first ajax.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var progressUpdater = setInterval(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: addressToProgressEndpoint,
        method: METHOD
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        //update UI with progress 
    });
}, 1000);
```

In your original ajax request in the success callback, call `clearInterval()` on progressUpdater to stop it

Comment: How can i call this function in my ajax. Can you tell me the detail. I have no idea how can i adjust this code with my ajax. @iismathwizard

Comment: @GiteshPurbia you should be able to implement this in your code. This is stackoverflow.com not writemycodeforme.com . In the success function of your original ajax call just add `clearInterval(progressUpdater)` and before that ajax call executes, add my section. I'm not going to show you how to update a UI with numbers.

Comment: @GiteshPurbia if it solved your problem upvote and mark it as accepted so others can quickly know the solution.