# How to make HTML Progress Bar Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a Progress Bar for the uploaded progress in my application. So far I have this

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <span style="border-left:5px solid #555555; padding-left:.5em">Upload File</span>
    <div style="margin-top:1em; margin-left:.8em;">                               
        <input type="file" name="file" class="inputfile" id="group-agent-file" accept=".csv"/>
        <label for="file" id="span-file-upload" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-right:.5em"></span>                                    
            <span id="span-file-name">Choose a file</span>
       </label>
   <div>
   <button type="button" id="btn-group-agent-upload" class="btn btn-primary" title="Upload">Upload</button>
</div>
<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" role="progressbar" id="progress-bar-upload">
          <span></span>
     </div>                                
</div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
var result = event.target.result;
var data = $.csv.toObjects(result);
var length = data.length;
var count = 0;
var percent;

$.each(data, function (key, val) {

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function(){
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
                console.log('progress', evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
            };
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/Insert_Bulk_Agent",
        data: JSON.stringify(val),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            count = count + 1;
            percent = count / length * 100;

            $("#progress-bar-upload").css("width", percent + "%");
            $("#progress-bar-upload span").text(percent + "% Complete");
            console.log("Finished " + count + " of " + length + " employees.");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            alert("error in Insert_Bulk_AgentInfo()");
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        }

    });

});
```

it works fine but I think the html can't process enough that sometimes the `width` percentage is delayed. How can I do this? and what may be the drawbacks when I use `setInterval`.

Comment: in this case your progressbar will be update only when image fully uploaded and response comes from server.  You should use setIntervel to get progress of image in every seconds or mili seconds.

Comment: how can i use this on my code?

Comment: look into this it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390776/call-another-ajax-inside-ajax-till-first-will-complete

Comment: are you sending the progress from from your api. What your are doing within IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/Insert_Bulk_Agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get upload progress in jQuery you need to attach Event-Listener to the **progress** event.

You can do something like this in jQuery

```
$.ajax({
xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total);
            //Update the progress bar
        }
   });

   return xhr;
},
type: 'POST',
url: "/upload/path",
data: { YOUR UPLOAD DATA },
success: function (data) {
}
});
```

This would work the same for plain js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "/upload/path", true);
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total);
    //Update the progress bar
  }
}
xhr.onload = function (response) {
  // handle success/error here
}
xhr.setRequestHeader(SET_HEADERS);
xhr.send(UPLOAD_DATA);
```

Comment: Can you give me line number or the line in which you received the error?

Comment: I fixed it but it's just go straight to 100%

Comment: That could be because either you are testing it locally or file content is too small.

Answer (score 2):

success function will be call when your ajax call gets completed.
You should use xhr function instead of success.

```
xhr: function(){
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){ 
                    console.log('progress', evt.loaded/evt.total*100); 
                    var percentageCompleted = evt.loaded/evt.total*100;
                    updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));
                    if(percentageCompleted == 100){
                        $("#p_custom_message_body").html('<p>Storing training data</p><img src="media/images/loading.gif">');
                    }
                } ;
                return xhr ;
            }
```

After that update progress bar in another function :-

```
    function updateUploadPercentage(progress) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    elem.style.width = progress + '%'; 
    elem.innerHTML = progress * 1 + '%';
}
```

Comment: I am having this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia At which line the console is indicating error?

Comment: I fixed it but it's just go straight to 100%

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia If you upload a file of larger size you can see the progress bar will increase slowly.